# reuse fragments in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android

**MY PROBLEM**
I am creating an Android app where the user swipes through a load of cards (like tinder)
Each card is VERY UI heavy (has a google map view and an admob ad)
I tried loading the list into a fragment adapter. This means a fragment for every single item. This is very memory intensive as I am creating about 30 google map views and 30 admob views for the 30 items.
My nexus 5 unsurprisingly crashes under this unnecessary heavy load.

**My attempted solution**
I have created 3 instances of the fragment.Loaded these fragments into a HashMap.

//for currently displayed fragment
key = 0

//for previous page
key = -1

for next page
key = 1

I keep the previous index.
On the getItem method of the adapter I detect if the user has gone to the previous page or the next page.
I get the associated fragment and return it.

My problem is I keep receiving exceptions like:
IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

I have tried detaching and/or removing the fragment but no luck :(

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Play ViewPager example...

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

In the getItem(int position) you have to create a new Fragment instance, old fragments should be destroyed when the setOffscreenLimit has been reached. I get the feeling originally you were creating all 30 Fragments at once?

Comment: thanks for this
but it's not what I am after  
I want to reuse fragments rather than create 30 instances in total  
thanks

Comment: You would'nt have 30 instances in total.... just 2 times the value of setOffscreenLimit (left and right) the pager adapter would destroy them when it's outside of these bounds and recreate when needed

Answer (score 0):

take a look at android's effective navigation sample for proper use of fragmentstatepageradapter.
http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/EffectiveNavigation.zip

I recommend put your admob in the main activity below viewpager. so u dont need to restart it everytime. and google map inside swipe view is not recommended by google as it is hard to handle both swipe and map zoom features. So simply use static map api it provides a screenshot of map according to the coordinates u provide and implement an onclick method to launch map as another activity.